# Reference request for functorial approach to classifying spaces

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms, classifying-spaces

In the introduction to Bott and Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology*, there was mention that

> ...there was no time left within the scope of our book to explain the functorial approach to classifying spaces in general and to make the connection with the Eilenberg--MacLane spaces.

Is there a good reference that has covered this material?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One source is [*Algebraic Topology* by Tammo Tom Dieck](https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=86), section 14.4.

Comment: @C.F.G: I don't think it's free. The print version of the book contains the usual copyright notice, "all rights are reserved" etc. Like many copyrighted works these days, there might be pirated PDF versions posted on the internet, but they're almost certainly illegal.

Comment: I see the pdf with the size of it (e-Book PDF (4648 KB)) in the above of page, I thought it is free!

Comment: This is a lovely text, thanks.  Functoriality shows up throughout the text, and it's used in several proofs.  Chapter fourteen on bundles indeed mentions that it aims to "compare classifying spaces of different groups and discuss the functorial properties of classifying spaces..."